# Python if statement problems

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make something work with if statements, but instead of choosing the correct one, it chooses all of them. So, the code below:

```
money=100

if money==100:
    print('You buy a pair of headphones')
    money-=100
if money<50:
    print('You buy a movie')
        money-=25
if money<10:
    print('You buy a burger')
    money-=5
```

Returns this:

```
You buy a pair of headphones
You buy a movie
You buy a burger
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 11):

Use `elif`

```
money=100

if money==100:
    print('You buy a pair of headphones')
    money-=100
elif money<50:
    print('You buy a movie')
    money-=25
elif money<10:
    print('You buy a burger')
    money-=5
```

each possibility is now part of the same block, so only one decision will be made rather then the sequential run through you have with plain `if`s

Comment: I'm trying to understand...your answer is of course good, but why wouldn't the code from OP work in the case money is 100 ?

Comment: @Bartdude because immediately after it is decremented by `100` and then the next (separate) `if` statement runs

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than one condition and you want to execute only one if its match your criteria then use

> "if elif keywords"

In your case, code will be

```
money = 100
if money == 100:
    print('You buy a pair of headphones')
    money -= 100
elif money <= 50 and money >=25:
    print('You buy a movie')
    money -= 25
elif money <= 10 and money >=5:
    print('You buy a burger')
    money -= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Or do something like this:

```
prices = {'100':'headphones', '50':'movie', '10':'burger', 5}
money = 100
for price in prices: 
    if money >= price: 
        print 'You buy a ', prices[price]
        money -= price
        break
```

It's not the same to the letter, but you can see that it's a lot more compact.  It's easier to add a new case.  And the logic makes sense - I should be able to buy anything that I have the money to pay for.

I'd encapsulate it in a method, too:

```
prices = {'100':'headphones', '50':'movie', '10':'burger', 5}
def buy(money):
    message = 'You could not afford anything'
    for price in prices: 
        if money >= price: 
            message = 'You buy a ' + prices[price]
            money -= price
            break
    return message
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because all the conditions are true,so you get all the outputs.
Instead

```
money = 100
if money == "100":
   print("You buy a pair of headphones.")
   money = 100
elif money <="50" and => "25":
    print("You buy a movie.")
    money = 25

elif money <= "25" and => "10":
     print("You buy a burger.")
     money = 5
```